# How can i change the backround color of a rectange by clicking on a checkbox

Tags: wpf, blend

Im Using Blend and have the following Problem:

How can i Change the Background Color of a rectangle by clicking on a checkbox? When i go via right click, edit template and then edit a copy i can only edit the current object. In this cas it would be the checkbox. But i want to use the checkbox to edit the style of a rectange object. Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried. Unfortunately it's hardly possible that people will write your whole code without knowing that you have at least done something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind to the `IsChecked` property and use a `ValueConverter`

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cb" />
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource CheckedToBackgroundConverter}}" />
```

the value converter

```
public class CheckedToBackgroundConverter: IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return value is bool && (bool)value ? Brushes.Blue : Brushes.Red;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
  }
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: this do it for me thanks. i just wondered if there is a way to do this via the blend gui whithout writing any code by yourself?